# Multiline I18n in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

this is a simple question but i cannot really find the answer somewhere. How do you handle multiline translations in i18n in Rails ?

What i currently have is something like :

```
error:
  code:  "This is the first line of the text and at some point it becomes too big. 
          So now i continue here."
```

This works, i suppose because it's translated into html where spaces do not really matter if not in a pre tag. I feel this is not the correct way, though. And if so, what is really the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This really isnt an I18n question as probably a yaml question.  Have you tried:

```
 body : |
   This is a multi-line string.
   "special" metacharacters may
   appear here. The extent of this string is
   indicated by indentation.
```

I placed the above in test.yml and in irb:

```
irb(main):012:0> x= YAML.load(IO.read('test.yml'))
=> {"body"=>"This is a multi-line string.\n\"special\" metacharacters may\nappear here. The extent of this string is\nindicated by indentation.\n"}
irb(main):013:0> x["body"]
=> "This is a multi-line string.\n\"special\" metacharacters may\nappear here. The extent of this string is\nindicated by indentation.\n"
```

For your specific example try:

```
error:
  code: |
    Some really
    long error
    message here
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit ? what is the idea ? You put a | and then your string below using the same indentation ? I can't really get it to work.

Comment: Updated my answer.. Yes you use a | after the key and begin the multiline text indented and maintain the indentation for the long string.